# Moq: mocked virtual method is still being executed instead of returning specified value

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a WPF application and i want to test the following method, it converts a html to a list of "Aangifte" objects:

```
public async Task<List<Aangifte>> GetAangiftes(int pageSize, int page)
        {
            List<Aangifte> aangifteList = new List<Aangifte>();
            try
            {
                var html = await _taxOnWebConnector.RetrieveAangiftesHtml(pageSize, page); //Mock method in tests
                HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
                document.LoadHtml(html);
                var aangifteTable = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"mandatesList\"]/table[1]").FirstOrDefault();
                var dataRows = aangifteTable.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.Attributes.Count == 1);
                foreach (var row in dataRows)
                {
                    aangifteList.Add(ConvertHtmlRowToAangifte(row));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Error retrieving aangiftes: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return aangifteList;
        }
```

I want to mock the virtual method:

```
public virtual async Task<string> RetrieveAangiftesHtml(int pageSize, int page)
```

So my unit test is:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task GetAangiftes_ShouldReturnAangiftesFromHtml()
        {
            using (var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose())
            {
                mock.Mock<TaxOnWebConnector>()
                    .Setup(x => x.RetrieveAangiftesHtml(10, 0))
                    .Returns(Task.FromResult(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "AangifteHtmlTestPage.txt"))));

                var aangiftes = await _aangifteController.GetAangiftes(10, 0);
            }
        }
```

I also tried:

```
[Fact]
        public async Task GetAangiftes_ShouldReturnAangiftesFromHtml()
        {
            var moqTaxOnWebConnector = new Mock<TaxOnWebConnector>();
            moqTaxOnWebConnector.Setup(x => x.RetrieveAangiftesHtml(10, 0))
                .ReturnsAsync(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "AangifteHtmlTestPage.txt")));
            var aangiftes = await _aangifteController.GetAangiftes(10, 0);
        }
```

I haven't gotten past this point because

```
RetrieveAangiftesHtml(int pageSize, int page)
```

is dependant on actions done in the WPF view. This doesn't happen in a test and the method get's stuck in an infinite loop.

When i debug my test, i see that it is still executing the method instead of returning the specified return value. Why is this?

Comment: Have you initialized the service your are testing injecting the mock? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/unit-test-using-mock-object-in-dependency-injection/

Comment: The act of creating a mock doesn't mean everything that depends on that Type will now be mocked. You have to use the mock in place of the true implementation. What I think Mr.Deer is saying is that you need to inject the mock.Object into `_taxOnWebConnector` on the controller.

Comment: Thank you both! @Mr.Deer , Crowcoder I added constructor dependency injection and passed the mock object in the constructor like: AangifteController(moq.object)